# Android: ListView scroll to position = Item bounds exceeded

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this issue: When I click a button, I select the next item in a ListView with `smoothScrollToPosition(index)`.

But I have this result:
[image]

I try to set the width of item with the side of the parent in this mode:

```
convertView.setMinimumWidth(((FrameLayout)parent.getParent().getParent()).getMeasuredWidth());
```

But the problem remains...

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the item  view width 'MATCH_PARENT' ?  and try to set any padding & Margins to 0... I wonder if the margins are taken into account in the scrollToPosition computation...

Comment: Yes. MATCH-PARENT for the item and no margin/padding are set.